# Argument of type 'Props' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<otherProps[] | null>'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

Context: I have two components (Coin, Activity) embedded within Home.tsx. Home.tsx fetches API endpoint on page load via axios inside a useEffect. The response is stored within the piece of state like so:

```
const [cryptos, setCryptos] = useState<HomeProps[] | null>(null)

useEffect(() => {
    axios.get('api')
.then((res)=> {
setCrypto(res.data)
})
},[])
```

Then the nodes are mapped out into their own individual Coin components.

```
 {cryptos
          ? cryptos.map((crypto) => {
              return (
                <Coin
                  key={crypto.id}
                  name={crypto.name}
                  image={crypto.image}
                  current_price={crypto.current_price}
                  id={crypto.id}
                  onSelectItem={() => {setActivity(crypto)}}
                />
              );
            })
          : null}
```

The Coin component has an OnClick function passed as props (onSelectItem), that should assign the data of the 'Clicked' coin component ('crypto') to this piece of state:

```
const [activity, setActivity] = useState <ActivityProps[] | null>(null)
```

Issue: The Argument type of 'HomeProps' is not an assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<ActivityProps[] | null>'

It seems that the 'crypto' data isnt a valid argument to the type Activity Props

These are the prop type interfaces for both 'activityInterface' and 'homeInterface'

```
export interface HomeProps {
  ath: number;
  atl: number;
  current_price: number;
  high_24h: number;
  id: string;
  image: string;
  low_24h: number;
  name: string;
  price_change_24h: number;
  price_change_percentage_24h: number;
  symbol: string;
}

export interface ActivityProps {
  current_price: number;
  high_24h: number;
  id: string;
  image: string;
  low_24h: number;
  name: string;
  price_change_24h: number;
  price_change_percentage_24h: number;
}
```

Ive tried to verify Im deconstructing the data properly within my type prop interface for 'ActivityProps', by logging 'crypto' to the console like so:

```
{cryptos
          ? cryptos.map((crypto) => {
              return (
                <Coin
                  key={crypto.id}
                  name={crypto.name}
                  image={crypto.image}
                  current_price={crypto.current_price}
                  id={crypto.id}
                  onSelectItem={() => console.log(crypto)}
                />
              );
            })
          : null}
```

This is what the 'crypto' data looks like when logged to the console after the Coin component is clicked:

```
{
"id":"bitcoin", 
"symbol":"btc",
"name":"Bitcoin",
"image":"https://assets.coingecko.com/coins/images/1/large/bitcoin.png?1547033579",
"current_price":29034,
"market_cap":564951550828,
"market_cap_rank":1,
"fully_diluted_valuation":610007895942,
"total_volume":4917541728,
"high_24h":29096,
"low_24h":28939,
"price_change_24h":38.48,
"price_change_percentage_24h":0.1327,
"market_cap_change_24h":-51884454.65686035,
"market_cap_change_percentage_24h":-0.00918,
"circulating_supply":19448900.0,
"total_supply":21000000.0,
"max_supply":21000000.0,
"ath":69045,
"ath_change_percentage":-57.9489,
"ath_date":"2021-11-10T14:24:11.849Z","atl":67.81,
"atl_change_percentage":42717.44695,
"atl_date":"2013-07-06T00:00:00.000Z",
"roi":null,
"last_updated":"2023-08-05T19:40:24.253Z"
```

}

If someone could explain the correct way to pass that data to setActivity(). That would be very helpful. Thanks

Comment: Are you looking to add multiple coins in the activity state?

Comment: The error says that `setActivity` expects an array but you pass a single element

Comment: @0xts No, the goal is to display more in-depth information about the individual Coin component clicked, if a different Coin is clicked, then that Coins information will be displayed in the activity window, the activity component should only hold information of one coin at a time

Comment: @ElijahMcCoy so why is `activity` state an array?